# What is the power voltage pin outs for a Playstation 5 PS5 power drive connector on the motherboard?

Tags: power, pcb, motherboard, playstation-5

I ripped off the drive power connector from the motherboard on a PS5 and looking to get this repaired, but I need to find the power pin outs in order to fix it. Where can I find the voltage pinouts diagrams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the power voltage pin outs for the Playstation 5 drive connector. I managed to rewire a 5V from the USB port and a 12V from the fan connector to the PS5 drive connector. Now the drive is working again!

[image]

[image]